# Unsure why I'm getting an IndexError-poker game code

Tags: python, index-error

I'm quite new to python, i'm trying to create a poker game framework and it was working but I've tried to add a function to give you the likelihood the other player has a better hand and when it runs it throwing up an index error and I have no idea what's causing it. The following code block is the function where the error is coming up. I'll link the full code in a github repository below so you can run it, the sections called three_kind_check(),two_pair_check(),pair_check() and high_card_check() have been where the error has cropped up. Sorry this is quite cluttered and unclear. Any help would be appreciated

https://github.com/Doug160516/Poker-Game/blob/main/limit%20hold%20em.ipynb

This is the offending function

def hand_prob(player):

```
"""
Gives a probability value to another player having a better hand and improving your hand on subsequent streets

args:
    player:A Player object type representing the player or an ai
Returns:
    Current_win_prob:An integer representing the probability of the player hand being better than the opponents hand
Raises:
    AttributeError:If player is not a Player object type
"""

test_hole_cards=[]
test_community_cards=[]
for cards in player.hole_cards: #append players hole cards to a seperate list to prevent them being accidentally altered
    test_hole_cards.append(cards)
    
for cards in player.card_hand:
    for tests in test_hole_cards:
        if cards.rank==tests.rank and cards.suit==tests.suit: #appending non hole cards to player.card_hand
            pass
        else:
            test_community_cards.append(cards)
    

test_deck=Deck() #test deck to check all card combos
test_deck2=Deck() #second test deck because .remove() is giving error
test_deck2.all_cards.clear()
for cards in test_deck.all_cards: #removing player hole cards and community cards from deck so they cant be repeated
    for tests in player.card_hand:
        if cards.rank==tests.rank and cards.suit==tests.suit:
            pass
        else:
            test_deck2.all_cards.append(cards)
current_combo_num=0
current_better_combos=0
for combos in combinations(test_deck2.all_cards,2): #checking all possible card combos of opponent
    current_combo_num+=1
    card_com_a,card_com_b=combos
    alt_test_player=Player("alt",1)
    for cards in test_community_cards:
        alt_test_player.deal(cards)
    alt_test_player.deal(card_com_a)
    alt_test_player.deal(card_com_b)
    hand_value_check(player)
    hand_value_check(alt_test_player)
    if alt_test_player.hand_score>player.hand_score:
        current_better_combos+=1
        print("better")
    else:
        print("worse")
current_win_prob=((current_better_combos/current_combo_num)*100)



return current_win_prob
```

Comment: Can you include the full error stack from your terminal as part of the post?

Comment: It's saying I can't as it's improperly formatted code, I'll try and add it to my repository. Sorry-I've added it to the linked repository as Limit hold em IndexError.txt. Hope that helps

Comment: This issue I think has been solved, where I was looping over the two card lists, the parity check i was doing wasn't catching cards that were equal so it was adding a strange amount of cards to hands and it was slipping through a check for length in another function which then caused the IndexError.